# How are static constants handled?

Tags: actionscript-3, static

I am debating whether to put static constants that will be accessed throughout instances of a specific class within that class, or in a separate utility class that will be composed only of static constants but will never actually have any instances.

Is additional hardware space allocated for static variables every time a new instance of a class is created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constants are a great *semantic* tool that conveys to other developers that this is a common, runtime unchanging, value. You should definitely use them if that's what you need.

Performance-wise, it's possible that they are stored with the class definition, but I'm not sure (it's been too long since I was working with the AVM). However, *it shouldn't matter*. Unless you are creating *millions* of instances of this class, what you are describing is a micro-optimization and will have zero impact on the performance or memory usage of your app.